# How to use TrueTime's withSharedPreferences to get cached time?

Tags: android, caching, android-library

I am using a library  ['TrueTime'](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android)  for maintaining a constant time irrespective of user's device time.

As it uses SNTP for synchronizing time, it suggests limiting multiple calls by caching the response. This is mentioned in the readme section and suggests to use withSharedPreferences(context) for enabling cache.
I am not able to understand where to put this line of code.

I tried initialising TrueTime by this:

```
TrueTimeRx.build().withSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).initializeRx("time.apple.com")
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(date -> {
                Log.d("TrueTime", "TrueTime was initialized at: %s" + date);
            }, throwable -> {
                Log.e("TrueTime", "TrueTime init failed: ", throwable);
            });
```

But, it's still not working. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are initializing TrueTime in an Activity, you can just have the below code:

```
TrueTimeRx.build()
.withSharedPreferences(this)
.initializeRx("time.google.com")    
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
(date -> {
    Log.d("TrueTime", "TrueTime was initialized at: %s" + date);
}, throwable -> {
    Log.e("TrueTime", "TrueTime init failed: ", throwable);
});
```

You can also check the sample code given in the same git repo:
[TrueTime Sample2Activity](https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/instacart/library/sample/Sample2Activity.java)

Comment: I think you are just re-initializing TrueTime again. It will make the request to the NTP and save it to the cache. But once I have done this, I don't want to re-initialize again.

Comment: I am not sure if you are still seeing repeated NTP calls during inializeRX() call. I think withSharedPreference() option avoids the repeated network calls. Please check the documentation - Notes section: https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android

Comment: I checked the execution of the code step by step using the debugger and saw that it made the request every time and saved it in the cache but never used the cached value.